# How to write unitary transformation of matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transformation

Given the set of matrix,supposedly the transpose of conjugate IV will obtain the UB:

```
IV_transpose*UB(IV)=UB
```

However, I get the different output. Please see the code;

```
angle=60
UB = np.array([
    [1,0,0,0],
    [0,math.cos(4*math.radians(angle)),math.sin(4*math.radians(angle)),0],
    [0, math.sin(4 * math.radians(angle)), -math.cos(4 
    *math.radians(angle)),0],[0,0,0,-1]])

IV = [[1.0],[1.0],[0.0],[0.0]]

IVT=np.conj(IV).T
UBIV=np.matmul(UB,IV)
output=np.matmul(IVT,UBIV)
print (output)
print (UB)
```

This is my output:

```
IV_transpose*UB(IV)=[[ 0.5]]
UB=
[[ 1.         0.         0.         0.       ]
[ 0.        -0.5       -0.8660254  0.       ]
[ 0.        -0.8660254  0.5        0.       ]
[ 0.         0.         0.        -1.       ]]
```

My question is why `IV_transpose*UB(IV)!=UB`.
How to make it equal?
Thank you.

Comment: Di you track the array shapes of `IVT`, `UBIV`, etc?  What dos `UB(IV)` mean?  `UBIV@IVT` produces a 4x4 array with the same numbers as `UB`, but in a different arrangement.

Comment: Yes. I notify that they have different array shapes. `UB` is the rotational of Bob at `60 degree`. `IV` is the initialization vector. The `IV` should be rotated using the `UB`. The transpose of `IV` times the `UB(IV)` will give the result of `UB`, isn't it?